# Android studio Speech to text offline mode not working

Tags: android, android-studio, speech-to-text, offline-mode

I am trying to get speech to text working offline on an Android app I am developing in Android Studio. Here is the code I use to set up the speech recognizer.

```
    public void openSpeechMode(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

        if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Your device does not support Speech Input.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

This works fine when I am online, but when I am offline it does not work. I read that I need to ensure that I follow these steps below on my Android device... to ensure my device has the library necessary to work in offline mode.

```
1)Go to Settings
2)Click on “Language and input”
3)Select Google voice typing
4)Select Offline speech recognition
5)Install desired language
6)Once the download was done, turn off the internet and test it !!
```

I followed those steps and I do have English (UK) and English (US) installed on my android device. BUT the speech to text app still does not work when I am offline. When I click the microphone, I get the message saying "Network not connected" "try again".

Am I doing something wrong? Can anyone assist?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for setting your language preference.

```
String languagePref = "en-US";//as you have downloaded US english model
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, languagePref);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, languagePref); 
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, languagePref);
```

Comment: It doesn't help me. I also have the same problem. And still can't find a solution.